# how to post value of submited button in jquery form submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="IssueForm"  action="wh_sir_insert.php"  >
   <input name='id[]' type='checkbox' class="selectable" value='$col[8]' />
   <input type="submit" name="Build"  value="BuildSir" />
   <input type="submit" name="wht"    value="Proceed Your Transfer"  />
</form>
```

When I click the submit button, both value and form values are sent:

```
 $("input[name='Build']").click(function(){
     // some validation
 });
```

following are the posted values:

[image]

```
  $("input[name='wht']").click(function(){
    //validation code
  })
```

[image]

But when I submit the form through `jquery.submit()`, the values of the submit buttons are not posted:

```
 $("#IssueForm").submit();
```

[image]

On the server side, I pick an action based on the submitted type. How I can add extra post information with `$("elem").submit();` to send along type of action?

Please, note one way is through `$.ajax` Or `$.post` but it would require a huge effort to change all my code.

Below is my scenario:

```
 $("input[name='Build']").click(function(){

        var per=$("input[name='issueperson']");
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajaxloads/confirmuser.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:"username="+per.val()+"&ownership="+$("#ownership").text(),
            success:function(r){
                if(r.success){
                    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to Build SIR?");
                    if (agree){
                        $("#IssueForm").submit();
                        // To avoid Double Submission
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $("#admin_message").show();
                    $("#ErrorMessage").text(r.info);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

How I can send the value of submitted button along with the form submit?

Comment: May I ask, if it is needed to submit form by jquery rather than normal way in your case?

Comment: But when you trigger submit handler, which one is supposed to be submited???

Comment: @A. Wolff ,Ya you are right that's why i'm asking can i add extra value along `submit()` handler

Comment: @MarkS, In fact before submitting i'm doing an ajax request and after response i decide whether to submit the form or not

Comment: i have added my scenrio as well

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got to work in some way  by adding a extra Value with query string.

```
$("input[name='Build']").click(function(){

    var per=$("input[name='issueperson']");
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajaxloads/confirmuser.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:"username="+per.val()+"&ownership="+$("#ownership").text(),
        success:function(r){
            if(r.success){
                var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to Build SIR?");
                if (agree){
                   $("#IssueForm").attr("action","wh_sir_insert.php?Build=BuildSir");
                   $("#IssueForm").submit();
                }
            }
            else{
                $("#admin_message").show();
                $("#ErrorMessage").text(r.info);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```